# How to use logical indexing on multiple criteria

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a table that has a column containing values between 1 and 20. I want to filter the table such that I can show only certain discrete values, i.e. 3, 10, 12, and 19. The problem is writing this is cumbersome, especially since I want to write other criteria for filtering too.:

```
i = tb.subn==3 | tb.subn==10 | tb.subn==12 | tb.subn==19
```

If I use `i = tb.subn==[3 10 12 19]` then I get a :x4 boolean matrix. How can I get that into just one column?

If it were `&`, I suppose I could use prod(tb.subn==[3 10 12 19],2) but I can't figure out `or`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ismember(tb.subn, [3, 10, 12, 19])`

Comment: That's it! Thanks for your help. I forgot about this function.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = all(tb.subn==[3 10 12 19], 2);
```

Note that this works only for very late matlab, while you solution will work better for all versions.

Comment: Thanks for helping. This works for `AND` but what about `OR`?

Comment: For OR, you will use any instead of all.